# I'm trying to convert my Json Object to pretty format using gson but encountering something odd

Tags: json, gson, pretty-print

```
    JsonObjectBuilder builder = factory.createObjectBuilder().add("input", input);
    JsonObject jsonData = builder.build();
    String jsonDataString = jsonData.toString();


    try {
        OutputStream jsonStream = new FileOutputStream(jsonPath);
        OutputStreamWriter jsonStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(jsonStream);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String prettyOutput = gson.toJson(jsonData);
        System.out.println(prettyOutput);
        jsonStreamWriter.write(prettyOutput);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
```

The output I get is weird:

It adds '"value":' before every string value of a key.
[image]

My JSON data is something like this:

```
{
    "input": {
        "record0": {
            "Active": "",
            "Level": "",
            "Name": "Pre-Session",
            "Description": "",
            "Record": "",
            "Field": "",
            "Std. Rule": "",
            "Ext. Rule": "//Updated By: Sukanya Dasgupta On: 25-Jan-2016"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to the image on the link to see how my gson output is.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expect but I think the problem is that `public String toJson(Object src)` loses type information :

> This method should be used when the specified object is not a generic
>   type. This method uses Object.getClass() to get the type for the
>   specified object, but the getClass() loses the generic type
>   information because of the Type Erasure feature of Java.

Comment: But I'm using a JsonData object as the specified object, and this is how I see most people pretty print JsonData, so it should technically work. I don't see anything wrong with my code, or is there? Do you have any workaround for this?